# Is it possible to dynamically (NOT statically) tie build jobs on jenkins to specific nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I  have jenkins setup with 2 separate nodes. I also have a parent job that calls multiple jobs. One of these jobs is called multiple times during the build of the parent job (it does some cleaning for the workspaces between the rest of the jobs).

I would like to know if it's possible to dynamically tie builds of this job to specific node?

As I mentioned the job cleans the workspaces and obviously I need that to be done on both nodes during the build of the parent job. I also don't want to create 2 separate jobs that does the exact same thing and the only difference is the checkbox that statically ties each to different nodes. Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding [Node label plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-Label) and parameter

This will make "label" as parameter. You may small logic to pass this parameter.

Comment: Once you are able solve this, you may provide a detailed answer. That will be useful for visitors..

Comment: tried it, worked like a charm. Thanks again :).
I want to provide a fully detailed walk-through with screenshots as you requested. Should I do it in a separate answer or as comment here?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of specialized task could be done more succinctly using the [Workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

```
node('first') {
  sh 'rm -rf *' // or when 1.11 released: deleteDir()
  // more work…
}
node('second') {
  sh 'rm -rf *'
  // …
}
```

Or you can use the `parallel` step to run these things concurrently, etc.

You can also use `build` to start builds of other projects in various ways, though you then lose the advantage of being able to see the entire process in one script, and you may also lose control of the exact workspace being used by the downstream build (especially if it is marked concurrent-capable).

Comment: I suppose you misunderstood the question. I wanted to have a parameter "node" so that whenever I build a certain job to be able to choose it a node to build it on. This was already achieved through "Node label plugin". 
Thanks for your reply anyways :)